# Why is Titanium only building an iphone project when I want an iPad app?

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a Titanium Alloy project that I am working on. When I select Run as > iPad simulator in Titanium Studio it runs the iPad simulator with my app in fullscreen. However, when I look in the build folder I can only see an iphone folder. If I run that Xcode project and target an iPad device (hardware) the app window is small with the "x2" button in the corner.

I have looked through the tiapp.xml file and enabled/disabled `target device="iphone"` and messed around with other settings, done a clean build etc but still no joy.

Thanks in advance. Here are some of my tiapp.xml settings -

```
<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>
    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
        <manifest>
            <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="17"
                android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
            <application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules/>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">true</target>
        <target device="ipad">true</target>
        <target device="iphone">false</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">true</target>
        <target device="tizen">true</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.1.3.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not creating the project correctly, You will have to create the project in the following way for iPad support.

1. File -> New -> Mobile Project.
2. In the wizard window select default alloy and press next.
3. Give name and AppId and select the supported platforms below you have to check the iPad option for the iPad support. If you haven't checked that you wont be able to support iPad.

That's All.

Thanks 
Nadeem

Comment: I created the app using the command line tools - Titanium and Alloy

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but I just found this solution:

Open the Xcodeproject and go to:
Project -> Deployment -> Targeted Device Families -> there select iPad only

Then build it from Xcode:

- Product -> Build for running
- Product -> Archive

(My problem was a bit different, but it answers the question. I was trying to publish an app to the App Store but it said it required iPhone screenshots.)